# Ignore RuntimeWarning: compiletime version 2.6 of module 'extension' does not match runtime version 2.7

Tags: python, python-extensions

After moving to python 2.7, I am getting the following warning:

`/opt/python/python-2.7/lib64/python2.7/pkgutil.py:246: RuntimeWarning: compiletime version 2.6 of module 'extension' does not match runtime version 2.7`

If I understand it correctly, I need to recompile the shared objects and link them against python 2.7. But that will take some time as the number of such extensions is rather large in my case.

In the meantime, is it OK to ignore the warning? What side effects does it have?

Comment: Depends on the module. For some, the error message can be simply ignored, but there might be others that use Python API that has changed between the 2 versions (imagine such an extension that calls a Python function that in 2.6 was having 2 arguments while in 2.7 has 3), in this case you'll most likely get a segfault.

Comment: I am not getting any segfaults or crashes - I've verified that. I am more concerned about any subtle changes that could change the functionality without visible breakage.

Comment: Yes in theory that could happen too (although I think there's a small chance). Also, the warning itself might mess some programs that parse the output (although it's  not the nicest method) of other (Python) programs.